# how can I measure traffic for Httpd/Ftp and SSH

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos, web

Is there any way to measure httpd/ftpd and sshd trafic per user basis.

Answer (score 0):

The httpd server keeps a log which includes user ID (if basic auth is used) and bytes sent.  The ftpd should have something similar but you may have to enable a detailed logging.  I'm not sure about sshd.  It may or may not have a detailed logging option.

Answer (score 0):

The [Apache::Traffic](http://search.cpan.org/~maurice/Apache-Traffic-1.02/Traffic.pm) server module seems to offer a simple way to log hits and bytes in/out per user.  you can just install that module and then run the `traffic` script to generate reports.

I don't see an obvious way to measure ssh or ftp traffic, other than the previous suggestion of increasing the logging detail and processing the logs.

There was a per-user IP accounting mechanism for the linux kernel called [ipacct](http://ramses.smeyers.be/homepage/useripacct/) but it seems way out of date now.